# Service not available in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a minikube cluster running locally (v0.17.1), with two deployments: one is a Redis instance and one is a custom app that is trying to connect to the Redis instance. My configuration is more or less copy/pasted from the official docs and the [Kubernetes guestbook example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/guestbook/all-in-one/guestbook-all-in-one.yaml).

Service definition and deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: poller-redis
  labels:
    app: poller-redis
    tier: backend
    role: database
    target: poller
spec:
  selector:
    app: poller
    tier: backend
    role: service
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: poller-redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: poller-redis
        tier: backend
        role: database
        target: poller
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: poller-redis
        image: gcr.io/jmen-1266/jmen-redis:a67b5f4bfd8ea8441ed66a8fcb6596f276017a1c
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: gcr-json-key
```

App deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: poller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: poller
        tier: backend
        role: service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: poller
        image: gcr.io/jmen-1266/poller:a96a452292e894e46339309cc024cac67647cc25
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: gcr-json-key
```

Relevant (I hope) Kubernetes info:

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes     10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP    24d
poller-redis   10.0.0.137   <none>        6379/TCP   20d

$ kubectl get deployments
NAME           DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
poller         1         1         1            1           12d
poller-redis   1         1         1            1           4d

$ kubectl get endpoints
NAME           ENDPOINTS           AGE
kubernetes     10.0.2.15:8443      24d
poller-redis   172.17.0.7:6379     20d
```

Inside the `poller` pod (custom app), I get environment variables created for Redis:

```
# env | grep REDIS
POLLER_REDIS_SERVICE_HOST=10.0.0.137
POLLER_REDIS_SERVICE_PORT=6379
POLLER_REDIS_PORT=tcp://10.0.0.137:6379
POLLER_REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=10.0.0.137
POLLER_REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT=6379
POLLER_REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PROTO=tcp
POLLER_REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://10.0.0.137:6379
```

However, if I try to connect to that port, I cannot. Doing something like:

```
nc -vz poller-redis 6379
```

fails.

What I have noticed is that I cannot access the Redis service via its ClusterIP but I can via the IP of the pod running Redis.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: How do you setup your redis? Did you set the authentication properly? Have you tried using a redis client to connect? While trying to reproduce your problem I have found that `nc` would not work but a redis-client would work but return a `(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.`

Comment: Have you got cluster networking deployed? Like weave-net, flannel or something similar? Could you include the output `kubectl get pod,svc,ep,deploy,rc --all-namespaces` ? Can you also test please if you can connect `10.0.0.137:6379` (not using name) from another container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out in the end, it looks like I misunderstood how the service selectors work in Kubernetes.

I have posted that my service definition is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: poller-redis
  labels:
    app: poller-redis
    tier: backend
    role: database
    target: poller
spec:
  selector:
    app: poller
    tier: backend
    role: service
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
```

The problem is that `metadata.labels` and `spec.selector` are different, when they should actually be the same. I still do not exactly understand why this is the case judging by the Kubernetes documentation, but there you have it. Now my service definition looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: poller-redis
  labels:
    app: poller-redis
    tier: backend
    role: database
    target: poller
spec:
  selector:
    app: poller-redis
    tier: backend
    role: database
    target: poller
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
```

I also now use straight up DNS lookup (i.e. `ping poller-redis`) rather than trying to connect to `localhost:6379` from my target pods.

Comment: This couldn't have been the problem. Service labels aren't a factor in selecting the pods to target.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to kube-dns possibly not running.

From inside the poller pod can you verify that poller-redis resolves?

Does the following work from inside the container?

```
nc -v 10.0.0.137
```

Comment: Is kube-dns supposed to run in every namespace? It is running in `kube-system`, but not `default` (which is the one I'm using).

Comment: No. You only need to have kube-dns in the kube-system namespace. It's a cluster wide service. Do not deploy it again.

Answer (score 0):

One kube-dns service running in `kube-system` is enough. Did you run `nc -vz poller-redis 6379` in pods which have same `namespace` as redis service?
`poller-redis` is simplified dns name of resdis service in same namespace. It will do not work in different namespace.
Since kube-dns is unavailable on nodes.  So if you want to run `nc` or `redisclient` in nodes, please use `clusterIP` of redis service to replace dns name.